# Why am I requred to include a trailing forward-slash for express routing?

Tags: regex, node.js, rest, express, routes

For example, I have a route that looks similar to this:

```
router.get("/container/:containerID/items", ctrlItems.itemRead);
```

This **does not** work.  However, the following route **does**:

```
router.get("/container/:containerID/items/", ctrlItems.itemRead);
```

Note the trailing "/" after items.

Why was I required to do this?  I didn't have to include trailing forward-slashes in any of my other routes that looked as follows:

```
router.get("/container/:containerID", ctrlContainer.containerRead);
router.get("/container", ctrlStuff.stuffRead);
```

What makes the other route special?  Is it something to do with the fact that the path includes (but does not end with) a variable name (containerID)?

**Edit:** This may have been a result of an outdated file after all.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. The only reason I can think of it failing is that you are matching two of the same routes. Post the actual error, without it you'll only get blind guesses for answers.

Comment: @cdbajorin - this problem may have actually been the result of an out-of-date file.  I have my project in Dropbox, and I'm running it from another machine.  I think one of the files didn't sync properly.